# Texstudio stopped being able to build the pdf files

Tags: installing, compiling, rendering

I worked on my Macbook Air for sometime using Texstudio when suddenly it can no longer build the PDF files and I am uncertain why, I have tried updating, I have tried looking around and quite frankly I am out of ideas now and seek help. I am running on OS X El Capitan 10.11.1, the tex studio version is 2.10.4, I have the latest macTex installed, I installed it today after clearing out the old installation. The message I get "Could not start the command" and then goes on with ending in "pdflatex" followed by the command line. I will include a screenshot of it
[image]
And I am out of ideas what to do now, I have tried fixing with these on what I saw on other questions but absolutely nothing happened or changed, it still keeps comming up. What am I doing wrong? Help would appriciated as this severely impacts my studies.

Comment: If you made an error somewhere you can locate it by moving `\end{document}` from the start to the end till it stops working -- on your macbook Air

Comment: Was there any resolution to this question?